# PHP - Concatenate text to 2 variables in 1 operation

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I've recently come across a bit of a problem about concatenating two string almost identically, but one would have more text than the other. Here is what I want to achieve and tried :

```
$var1 = $var2 = "the sky is ";  
$var1 .= "grey and ";
$var1 .= $var2 .= "blue";
```

Obviously this will not work but the desired result is :

```
$var 1 : "the sky is grey and blue"
$var 2 : "the sky is blue"
```

Another operation wouldn't be much here but it's more about knowing if it is possible.
I could make a third temporary var but I was wondering if i could avoid it, other solutions would have been to have only 1 variable and remove with substring operations.

Comment: this is micro optimisation and a waste of time imho

Comment: to help you understand, the operations in your 3rd line are executed from right to left, first `$var2 .= "blue"` then `$var1 .= (result of preceding)`

Comment: @delboy1978uk Yes it kinda is, it doesn't serve much but just satisfy my curiosity !

Comment: @Kaddath I'm aware it wouldn't work and understand this operation, as $var1 would get twice the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and more complicated variant:

```
$var1 = $var2 = "the sky is ";
$var1 .= "grey and ";
list($var1,$var2) = array_map(function($var){
    return $var .= 'blue';
},[$var1,$var2]);
```

Comment: That's indeed complicated but it does the job ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

@janmyszkier approach is cleaner but there are many ways to stick around just saw your word complicated so i did this for you what was really happening behind the scene

```
$text= ["the sky is ","grey and "];

list($var,$var2) = $text;

echo addSuffix('blue',$var);

echo addSuffix('blue',$var2);


function addSuffix($suffix,$value) {

  return $value.$suffix;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It does explain the operations, even though the results are not the expected ones, but that wasn't the goal of your comment I believe ?